# Performing MSBuild tasks in TFS only on _PublishedWebsites

Tags: tfs, build

I think the title is clear, but I will elaborate.

I have two websites (well, one website and one web app).

When I perform a build in TFS, the two seperate web apps get put into seperate folders underneath _PublishedWebsites

I would like to put a target in my web app's csproj that will only get executed in tfs that will do some merge (which I don't need help on).

Is there a target name I can create in my web.csproj that only tfs will run? What envirorment variables can I use to reference the _PublishedWebsites folder? $(OutDir)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a target that only TFS will run, but you can put a condition on a target so that it won't run in your Visual Studio builds. The MSBuild property is $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) - as you'd expect, it's set to true when building in Visual Studio.